# if not info.new_interface(): TypeError: 'str' object is not callable, although i have used correct syntax of str

Tags: python, command-line

```
import subprocess
import optparse


def mac_changer(interface, mac_add):
    subprocess.call("ifconfig" + str(interface)+" down", shell=True)
    subprocess.call("ifconfig" + str(interface)+" hw ether " + str(mac_add), shell=True)
    subprocess.call("ifconfig" + str(interface)+" up", shell=True)


def get_args():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", dest="new_interface", help="Selects Interface")
    parser.add_option("-m", "--MAC", dest = "new_mac", help="Changes the Mac Address")
    (options, arguments) = parser.parse_args()
    if not options.new_interface():
        parser.error("No interface specified")
    elif not options.new_mac:
        parser.error("No Mac address found in command line")

    return options


options = get_args()
mac_changer(options.interface, options.new_mac)
```

I have been working on a mac changer recently and it returns this this error, even though i do not use str function the entire code except when it's needed.

Comment: A `str` *object* is not the same thing as the `str` *function*. The error message tells you that you are treating a string as if it was a function. In any event -- what line is throwing the error? We shouldn't need to guess.

Comment: `if not options.new_interface:` should work

Comment: thanks for clarifying my silly mistake joran :).